# How to make a project's subdirectory read-only in eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, wordpress, readonly

How can I make a project's subdirectory read-only in eclipse?

The reason I need to do this is that I'm currently learning how to build a child theme in wordpress. I need to be able to view the parent theme's files but sometimes I edit the parent file (e.g. functions.php, style.css) instead of the child's file with the same name.

I know I could set the filesystem attributes recursively to read-only on everything other than my child theme, but I'm wondering if there's a better way? When I do this and I try to edit a read-only file, eclipse shows me a dialog offering to clear the attribute. This is not convenient because if I accidentally press enter or space before I realise there's a dialog, the default is to clear the attribute and then I have to set it again. Ideally I'd like to tell eclipse to not let me edit any files under some specific directories that I choose.

Thanks